# How to install System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I am trying to install the Sqlite framework [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)  . I've installed the precompiled binary for Windows, but in Visual Studio there is no System.Data.SQLite.  I've also added a configuration file with this:

```
<configuration>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
        <add name="SQLite Data Provider" 
             invariant="System.Data.SQLite" 
             description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
             type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

I still cannot import the library.  I'm not sure how to get this working. In XCode I would simply drag the source files for the wrapper into the project, and add my sqlite db.  Not so easy here I guess.  Also, on the Mac I usually create my db structure through the bash shell using SQLite3.  How can I do this on Windows too?

Comment: You can always browse to find the assembly - it'll be in "C:\Program Files\System.Data.SQLite\bin". Did you tick the 'install into the GAC' checkbox when you installed it?

Comment: Thanks! Still getting the hang of the Microsoft world.  Any idea on how to create an sqlite database via the cmd?

Comment: @spentak Use `sqlite3 my_new_database.sqlite` - see [Command Line Shell For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html)

Comment: I know how to use sqlite at the terminal, the problem is I don't know how to get it setup on windows. 'sqlite3' is not recognized

Comment: I have this same issue, but now with VS2019, I have copied the sqlite3.h into VS project, I've tried every solution I can find here, I don't understand what nuget is, but I found one and have it ready for use haha. I HATE windows too spentak, XCode is not good, and it;s better then this nightmare project file.

Comment: It can be installed with Nuget as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76340509/using-sqlite-from-a-c-sharp-console-application-built-with-the-command-line/76340741#76340741).

Answer (score 0):

O.o I have used the codeplex Sqlite version and this woks fine for me :D

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go for the older version from [the original website](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/). It comes with an installer that solves all the configuration headaches for you. I only used it in VS 2008 though, there it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Add reference from nuget packages (search for sqlite online in nuget manager).

Answer (score 0):

You need to browse for the reference after the setup package is installed:
Solution Explorer, rigth click references, add reference, browse, and then select the system.data.sqlite.dll.

Hope this helps.