# Using Sqlite from a C# console application (built with the command line)

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, nuget

I'm new to C# and I want to use a third library party library for the first time, in this case the sqlite library.
My problem: I haven't got enough memory on my computer to install Visual Studio, so I need to compile and run everything from the terminal.

I created my app using the command

```
dotnet new console -o SqliteTestApp -f net7.0
```

The tutorial where I got the command from is [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/create)

Then I wrote the following code in Program.cs.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SQLiteDemo
{
   class Program
   {

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello Sqlite!");
         CreateConnection();
      }

      static SQLiteConnection CreateConnection()
      {

         SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
         // Create a new database connection:
         sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");
         // Open the connection:
         try
         {
            sqlite_conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection worked!");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection didn't work!");
         }
         return sqlite_conn;
      }

      
   }
}
```

My SqliteTestApp.csproj-file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The code above does not compile with the command

```
dotnet run
```

,because I don't include the SQLite library.
My question: How do I modify this project-file , so I can use the SQLite-library and what commands to run from the command line. I know you somehow need to know how to use nuget.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: search https://nuget.org for the package you want. Each package shows you how to add the package to your project, even when you are only working with dotnet from commandline (look for .Net CLI)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know, i.e. how to include this library but libraries in C# in general

Answer (score 3):

Run this command in the command prompt to add SQLite package reference:

```
dotnet add package System.Data.SQLite --version 1.0.117
```

I assume you will use the SQLite library at [System.Data.SQLite Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dotnet cli to add a package in a csproj. Search the desired package on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/) and choose `.NET Cli` to display the command.

In you case, to add `System.Data.SQLite`, you can execute this command in the csproj repository :

```
dotnet add package System.Data.SQLite
```

The result will be :

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite" Version="1.0.117" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```